# Deletar elemento array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma calculadora(estou usando para estudar), e coloquei um botão que deveria apagar o ultimo número do array, porém quando eu clico ele me retorna um erro:

> script.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: nums.pop is not a function
>       at limpa (script.js:16)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:12)

```js
let tela = document.getElementById('visor');
let verifica;
let nums = [];
let oldnum = 0;
let operation;

function mostranum(num){
  tela.innerHTML += num;
  nums += num;
}

function limpa(){
  nums.pop();
  tela.innerHTML = nums;
}

function operator(ope){
  let regx = /^[0-9]{1,8}$/;
   
  if (regx.test(nums) == true) {
    oldnum = nums;
  } else {
    alert('digite ate 8 digitos ');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='calculadora'>
    <button id='clear' onclick="limpa()">C</button>
    <div id="visor"></div>
    <button class="num" id="n7" value="7" onclick="mostranum(7)">7</button>
    <button class="num" id="n8" value="8" onclick="mostranum(8)">8</button>
    <button class="num" id="n9" value="9" onclick="mostranum(9)">9</button>
    <button class="ops" id="sum" onclick="operator('sum')">+</button>

    <button class="num" id="n4" value="4" onclick="mostranum(4)">4</button>
    <button class="num" id="n5" value="5" onclick="mostranum(5)">5</button>
    <button class="num" id="n6" value="6" onclick="mostranum(6)">6</button>
    <button class="ops" id="subtract" value="-" onclick="operator('subtract')">-</button>

    <button class="num" id="n1" value="1" onclick="mostranum(1)">1</button>
    <button class="num" id="n2" value="2" onclick="mostranum(2)">2</button>
    <button class="num" id="n3" value="3" onclick="mostranum(3)">3</button>
    <button class="ops" id="multiplication" value="*" onclick="operator('multiplication')">*</button>

    <button class="num" id="0" value="0" onclick="mostranum(0)">0</button>
    <button class="ops" id="float" value=".">.</button>
    <button class="result" id="result" onclick="operator('result')" >=</button>
    <button class="ops" id="division" value="/" onclick="operator('division')">/</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inicialmente, `nums` foi declarado como *array*:

> ```
> let nums = [];
> ```

No entanto, na função `mostranum`, você está tentando utilizar o operador `+=` em um array. Nesse caso, o *array* será convertido para uma string, veja:

```js
let arr = [];
arr += 5;

console.log(typeof arr, arr); // string 5
```

Desse modo, você está recebendo o erro já que uma string não tem o método `pop` em seu protótipo. Em suma, é errado utilizar o operador `+=` para inserir um novo item ao fim do *array*.

Nesses casos, utilize o método [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```js
let tela = document.getElementById('visor');
let verifica;
let nums = [];
let oldnum = 0;
let operation;

function mostranum(num) {
  tela.innerHTML = parseFloat(tela.innerHTML || 0) + num;
  nums.push(num);
}

function limpa(){
  nums.pop();
  tela.innerHTML = nums;
}

function operator(ope){
  let regx = /^[0-9]{1,8}$/;
   
  if (regx.test(nums) == true) {
    oldnum = nums;
  } else {
    alert('digite ate 8 digitos ');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='calculadora'>
    <button id='clear' onclick="limpa()">C</button>
    <div id="visor"></div>
    <button class="num" id="n7" value="7" onclick="mostranum(7)">7</button>
    <button class="num" id="n8" value="8" onclick="mostranum(8)">8</button>
    <button class="num" id="n9" value="9" onclick="mostranum(9)">9</button>
    <button class="ops" id="sum" onclick="operator('sum')">+</button>

    <button class="num" id="n4" value="4" onclick="mostranum(4)">4</button>
    <button class="num" id="n5" value="5" onclick="mostranum(5)">5</button>
    <button class="num" id="n6" value="6" onclick="mostranum(6)">6</button>
    <button class="ops" id="subtract" value="-" onclick="operator('subtract')">-</button>

    <button class="num" id="n1" value="1" onclick="mostranum(1)">1</button>
    <button class="num" id="n2" value="2" onclick="mostranum(2)">2</button>
    <button class="num" id="n3" value="3" onclick="mostranum(3)">3</button>
    <button class="ops" id="multiplication" value="*" onclick="operator('multiplication')">*</button>

    <button class="num" id="0" value="0" onclick="mostranum(0)">0</button>
    <button class="ops" id="float" value=".">.</button>
    <button class="result" id="result" onclick="operator('result')" >=</button>
    <button class="ops" id="division" value="/" onclick="operator('division')">/</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada, tem alguma maneira de não aparecer essa virgula quando estou deletando os numeros?